# How to clean location data in power bi

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, data-cleaning

I've currently got two tables. I have one table with a list of locations as such:

> Zagreb (Croatia)
>
> Seattle, WA, USA
>
> New York City, NY
>
> Kazakhstan, Almaty

I also have a master list of 200k cities that looks as such:

> Zagreb | Croatia
>
> Seattle | USA
>
> New York City | USA
>
> Almaty | Kazakhstan

The output I want is to add a new column to the first table as below:

> Zagreb (Croatia) | Croatia
>
> Seattle, WA, USA | USA
>
> New York City, NY | USA
>
> Kazakhstan, Almaty | Kazakhstan

This updated from a live source that I can't control the data quality from so any solution must be dynamic.

Any ideas appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach would be to add a custom column to the first table that searches the string for any cities that appear in the second table `City` column.

```
 = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "City",
       (L) => List.Select(Cities[City], each Text.Contains(L[Location], _)))
```

This gives a list of matching cities. Expand that list to get the following:

[image: Cities]

You can then merge with the `Cities` table (matching on the `City` columns from each table) to pull over the `Country` column.

---

Here's the full text of my query from the advanced editor:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WikpML0pNUtBwLspPLMlM1FSK1YlWCk5NLCnJSdVRCHfUUQgNdgQL+qWWK0TmF2UrOGeWVOoo+EWCRb0TqxKzM4pLEvN0FBxzchNLKpViYwE=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Location = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Location", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "City", (L) => List.Select(Cities[City], each Text.Contains(L[Location], _))),
    #"Expanded City" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom", "City"),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Expanded City",{"City"},Cities,{"City"},"Cities",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Cities" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Cities", {"Country"}, {"Country"})
in
    #"Expanded Cities"
```

Answer (score 0):

Name the 1st table as "location",including 1 column named "location".
Name the 2nd table as "city",including 2 columns named "city" and "country".
The code is:

```
let
    location = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="location"]}[Content],
    city = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="city"]}[Content],
    result = Table.AddColumn(location,"city",each Table.SelectRows(city,(x)=>Text.Contains([location],x[city]))[country]{0})
in
    result
```